# Sagemaker suddenly unable to install python packages, missing python-dev

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Not sure why, but sagemaker complaining about unable to install certain python packages. This is automatically deployed with cloudtemplate. Not sure how to go about installing python-dev on sagemaker.

```
    Running setup.py install for cymem: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-he9ui3pu/cymem/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-he9ui3pu/cymem/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-spf4a86a/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-he9ui3pu/cymem/
    Complete output (27 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cymem
    copying cymem/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cymem
    copying cymem/about.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cymem
    package init file 'cymem/tests/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cymem/tests
    copying cymem/tests/test_import.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cymem/tests
    copying cymem/cymem.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cymem
    copying cymem/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cymem
    copying cymem/cymem.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cymem
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
    
    running build_ext
    building 'cymem.cymem' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/cymem
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c cymem/cymem.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/cymem/cymem.o -O3 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wno-strict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    cymem/cymem.cpp:4:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
Running setup.py install for cymem: finished with status 'error' ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-he9ui3pu/cymem/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-he9ui3pu/cymem/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-spf4a86a/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile cwd: /tmp/pip-install-he9ui3pu/cymem/ Complete output (27 lines): running install running build running build_py creating build creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6 creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cymem copying cymem/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cymem copying cymem/about.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cymem package init file 'cymem/tests/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file) creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cymem/tests copying cymem/tests/test_import.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cymem/tests copying cymem/cymem.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cymem copying cymem/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cymem copying cymem/cymem.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cymem warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping. running build_ext building 'cymem.cymem' extension creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6 creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/cymem x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c cymem/cymem.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/cymem/cymem.o -O3 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wno-strict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ cymem/cymem.cpp:4:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory #include "Python.h" ^~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1 ----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing python-devel for the c++ bindings.

```
sudo yum install python-devel
```

may help resolve the missing dependency.

Answer (score 0):

By using a later version of sagermaker image, it appear to resolve it.